# Split string matching a pattern JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have a **string** like this:

```
"First player vs. Second player &emsp;&emsp;&emsp; Percentage%"
```

*First player* and *Second player* **can be multiple words** and before the *Percentage%* I'm using three `&emsp;`.
How can I split this string to have an array containing *First player* and *Second player* (*Percentage* is not necessary)?

Comment: Where does the data of 'First Player' & 'Second Player' comes from? Hardcoded string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it

```js
const test1 = 'First player vs. Second player     Percentage&emsp'
const test2 = 'Ryu vs. Ken     100&emsp'

const extractPlayers= (string) => {
  const [firstPlayer, rest] = string.split(' vs. ')
  const secondPlayer = rest.split(' ').filter(x => x).slice(0, -1).join(' ').trim()
  
  return {firstPlayer, secondPlayer}
}

console.log(extractPlayers(test1))
console.log(extractPlayers(test2))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```js
const data=["First player vs. Second player &emsp;&emsp;&emsp; Percentage%",
            "Another first player vs. a second one  &emsp;&emsp;&emsp; Percentage%",
            "One     vs. Two&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;   Two Percentage%"];
            
const res = data.map(s=>s.match(/(.+?)\s+vs\.\s+(.+?)\s*\&emsp;\&emsp;\&emsp;/).slice(1));
console.log(res)
```

In the regexp I am looking for two matching groups `(.+?)`. These are non-greedy matches, as they are followed or preceded by `\s+` (one or more white space characters) and I *don't* want these whitespace characters in my matching groups.